# Can't print selected options value

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to print out the dropdowns text value, by selecting it by index. But it does not seem to work, see code below

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("FContent"))
optionslist = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("godKoerselsNr"))
select = optionslist.select_by_index(1)
selected = select.first_selected_option
print(selected.text)
```

Comment: try `print(select.text)` ?

Comment: If i try that i get a ```Error<class 'AttributeError'>```

Comment: Was your question solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** problem - indentation.
**Second** problem: you do not need an extra variable.

Try this:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("FContent"))
optionslist = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("godKoerselsNr"))
select = optionslist.select_by_index(1)
print(select.first_selected_option.get_attribute("value"))
```